# Find for each row the first non-null value in a group of columns and the column name

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1     col2     col3     Other
====================================
NULL     1        2        A
3        4        5        B
NULL     NULL     NULL     C
```

and I would like to get as result the following one with this rules:

- For each row find the first non-NULL value and set its value in `FirstValue` and set its column name in `ColName`
- If in a row all values are NULL, `FirstValue` and `ColName` are set to NULL
- keep `Other` column

Expected result:

```
FirstValue     ColName      Other
====================================
1             col2         A
3             col1         B
NULL          NULL         C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`:

```
val df2 = df.select(
    coalesce(df.columns.dropRight(1).map(col):_*).as("FirstValue"), 
    coalesce(df.columns.dropRight(1).map(c => when(col(c).isNotNull, lit(c))):_*).as("ColName"), 
    col("Other")
)


df2.show
+----------+-------+-----+
|FirstValue|ColName|Other|
+----------+-------+-----+
|         1|   col2|    A|
|         3|   col1|    B|
|      null|   null|    C|
+----------+-------+-----+
```